# Run Django server using the run button in visual studio code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, configuration, pycharm

In pyCharm we have this option where we can configure `Run button` to start the server by adding the same to the script path.

[image]

I wanted to do the same in visual studio code, so that whenever I click Run, my django server gets started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `launch.json` in the folder `.vscode` which sits in the same folder as your `manage.py`.

```
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
            ],
            "django": true
        },
    ]
}
```

You can create one by clicking `run & debug` and then at top menu green triangle click `add configuration` -> `python` -> `Django`

Comment: did not work for me, I clicked on Run->Run without debugging and its running this command on terminal `& 'C:\Users\hpoddar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\hpoddar\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.10.1336267007\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '65244' '--' 'c:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\WebDev\ReactComplete\DjangoReact\ArticlesApp\APIProject\manage.py'
`

Comment: After you have made the configuration, make sure when you run it, you select `Python: Django` and not `Python: Current File`, it should then show `'... APIProject\manage.py' 'runserver'` and start the local server...

Comment: How do I select the same? Also I am using python virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

You can change the configuration in the `Run and Debug` sidebar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. In vscode make sure your in the same folder as manage.py
2. From the menu bar at top of vscode select TERMINAL -> NEW TERMINAL. (will launch a terminal window).
3. In the terminal window type:  python manage.py runserver
4. Remember to keep the window open and minimized.

Answer (score 0):

To Run Server you must know few thing before that :

- Make sure that you are in the directory same as manage.py file of the
  project.
- To run any server you must provide command flag(an indicator for the
  command to what task to do)
  python3 manage.py
- To run server use command python3 manage.py runserver

In your case you are not in the same directory as of manage.py file
Can find the few important  flags in this link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/)